# Embed pictures for fixed range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to embed pictures in a file. The URL is in column C, starting from C4:C504. The pictures should be placed in column B, starting from B4. I already had a correct code (found online) but that one did just link the pictures so I couldn't send the files. All URLs are unique so the URL in C4 should correspondent with the picture in B4 etc.

So how do I embed pictures and make sure they will be placed in the right cells?

The code I found online:

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C504")
For Each cell In Rng
    filenam = cell
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
    Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
    xCol = cell.Column - 1
    Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
    With Pshp
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width
        If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height
        .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height)
        .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width)
    End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("B4").Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I already tried to replace some code from the one I was using, it worked for the embedding part but all pictures were placed in cell A1. Since I'm not really experienced with VBA it could be that I really messed up a lot.

```
Dim Pshp As Shape
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C504")
For Each cell In Rng
    filenam = cell
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=filenam, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100
    Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
    xCol = cell.Column - 1
    Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
    With Pshp
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width
        If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height
        .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height)
        .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width)
    End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("B4").Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I know I'll have to use the code below but I'm not sure how to fix the problem of getting the pictures in the right place.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=filenam, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=100, Height:=100
```

Answer (score 0):

- I strongly advise to not use the `On Error Resume Next`
- Use `.Pictures.Insert(filenam)` after going to the cell you want to insert the picture on.

**Try this:**

```
Sub trtrt()

Dim Pshp As Shape
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C504")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    filenam = cell
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & cell.row).Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
    Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
    If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
    xCol = cell.Column - 1
    Set xRg = Cells(cell.row, xCol)
    With Pshp
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        If .Width > xRg.Width Then .Width = xRg.Width
        If .Height > xRg.Height Then .Height = xRg.Height
        .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height)
        .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width)
    End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: It works until it cannot find a picture with the URL I think, because I get an error 1004. The URLs are created automatically based on a unique number and some VLOOKUPs. So sometimes a picture is not in the folder. Is there some solution for this?

Comment: I sent the file but the pictures are not appearing, so it seems they are not embedded and just linked again